# Using dependent type to generate compile error

Tags: scala, shapeless

Use case: Writing a generic function like

```
def tenantFilterQuery[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q, e: TableQuery[Q], id: Int)(implicit s: Session) :Query[Q,Q#TableElementType,Seq] = {
  e.filter(_.tenantId === id)
}
```

I am trying to add compile time intelligence that `e.filter(_.tenantId === id)` filter should ONLY be applied if for passed `T` there exists a property named `tenantId` else it'll not apply that filter if `T` didn't have that property.

Can this be worked out with dependent path types with or without using shapeless?

As a second step trying to come up with a way where when final `Query` is made and if `T` has property named `tenantId` it'll fail at compile time if it didn't have `filter` on `tenantId`. Think I should create a separate question for this one once first one is figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The second question is the easier one: you can just use a structural type, `T <: {def tenantId: Int}`, and then it's only possible to call this with such a `T`.

If you want the filter to happen for those types and not happen for another type, I guess you could do that by providing an implicit helper? Something like:

```
sealed trait Helper[T]{
  def applyToQuery[Q <: Table[T]](e: TableQuery[Q]): TableQuery[Q]
} 
trait LowPriorityHelper {
  implicit def withoutTenantId[T] = new Helper[T] {
    def applyToQuery[Q <: Table[T]](e: TableQuery[Q]): TableQuery[Q] = e
  }
}
object Helper extends LowPriorityHelper {
  implicit def withTenantId[T <: {def tenantId: Int}] =
    new Helper[T] {
      def applyToQuery[Q <: Table[T]](e: TableQuery[Q]): TableQuery[Q] =
        e.filter(_.tenantId === id)
    }
}

def doQuery[T: Helper] = { val e = ...; implicitly[Helper[T]].applyToQuery(e)...}
```

The `withTenantId` `Helper` will be passed for `T` that has a `tenantId`, and the `withoutTenantId` one otherwise.

Comment: I don't know this database library you're using, but it looks like you need to require that `Q` contain a `tenantId`. The same technique should work.